# Displaying iframe content on a facebook page from a custom url

Tags: facebook

I am trying to create a system which allows customers to add a Facebook page as an add-on to what our business offers. Ideally I want users to click a button from our site which creates a page for them on Facebook which contains an iFrame in which content is served by us from our site.

I've never done any work with Facebook before, I don't really understand how the whole app thing works (I don't really use it personally as well) and I'm not sure what the best way to achieve what we seek. I have read a few tutorials on the fb developer site, which were all completely out of date, but I created an app of type 'App on Facebook' that displays a canvas url with an iframe which displays some content.

However, what I really want is to do one of the following:

1) Create an app that can be added to someone's page, which takes a custom url and displays this url in the iframe on the canvas page.

For example, a user called **bob** initialises the facebook integration from our site, we automatically create a page for them, add the app we have created, and provide a url like **http://ourcustomurl.com/bob** which is a link to some content from our site which is then displayed in the iframe.

2) Another option I thought would be possible would be creating a new app for every user who enables the facebook integration from our site, and just setting the canvas url on creation. But this option doesn't sit well with me, we don't really want to create an app for people, but a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a Facebook Page or an App via the API

If i understand correctly you want page admins to install your app into a tab on their page, and have different content displayed on that page tab depending on which page it is.

Check this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/
The main takeaway you should have is that you can use the [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which is sent to your app to determine which Facebook Page the App is being loaded from and decide on your side which content to display based on that

Comment: ok thx for the info, bit annoying that you can't create a page via the api, not sure how I will find my way around that little problem

Comment: You shouldn't need to - I'm guessing in most cases your customers will already have a page and will be adding your app's content to that existing page - if not, you could just link them to facebook.com/pages/create.php and use the `manage_pages` permission from the API to see their list of owned pages and add your app to the appropriate one